# Next.js: Skipping generating static sites at build time (instead: only at runtime, as getStaticProps has no data in build phase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to use the same application for different customers, where there's a different database for each (which could be on-premise).
As a result, I have no data at the build phase (e.g. in CI/CD) that I could use to create static sites.

I thought about skipping generating the sites in `getStaticProps` via an environment variable.
When building the sites, I could tell Next.js to not use any data, something like this:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<HomePageProps> = async () => {
  const isBuildPhase = process.env.IS_BUILD;

  const data = isBuildPhase ? null : await fetchData();

  return {
    props: {
      data: data ?? null,
    },
    revalidate: 5 * 60,
  };
};
```

Now, I want to create the sites only at runtime (with `next start`), because at runtime, the built application has access to its database. In each `getStaticProps` the environment variable will be configured so data is fetched. When the application starts initially, it will generate all static sites when they're accessed.

Are there big downsides with this approach?

Are there maybe better solutions to this problem?

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered using [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) instead?

Comment: @juliomalves Sure, I'm using server-side rendering in some parts of the application, but having static sites is a much better user experience in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar requirement where the app needed to serve multiple tenants pages, but each tenant data is different. Which meant the app did not have access to data at build time and only runtime.

We leveraged `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to do this.

#### [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)

This method returns a `fallback` option `(true || false || blocking)`, which we can use to decide to show a loader on the UX or block until the actual page loads.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Return empty paths because we don't want to generate anything on build
  // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
  // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}
```

When using this method, there isn't a need to maintain `IS_BUILD` env variable. *(Depending on your specific use-case you may choose to use it or not)*

#### [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props)

This method does the actual data fetching based on the URL path params for a tenant.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // Run your data fetching code here
  const data = await fetch(params);
  return {
    props: data,
     // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
    notFound: !data,
  };
}
```

We also leverage [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration), to make sure that we refresh the page every `revalidate` seconds.

#### Pages

##### Single Template Tenants

When all the tenants share the same components, it's pretty straight forward:

```js
const SingleTenantPage = ({ data }) => {

  return <Component {...data} />;
};

export default SingleTenantPage;
```

##### Multi-Template Tenants

The actual page, just parses the props *(passed down from `getStaticProps`)*, and then loads the appropriate component for that page.

This way we leverage a single route for multiple tenants. `example.com/app/tenantA`, `example.com/app/tenantB`, `example.com/app/tenantC` all 3 routes can be served out of `pages/app/[slug]/index.js`.

Using `dynamic` imports, we make sure that only the component for a specific tenant is loaded. *(also helps in code splitting)*

```
// Dynamic Import so we load only the required bundles
const templates = {
  tenantA: dynamic(() => import(`../templates/tenantA`)),
  tenantB: dynamic(() => import(`../templates/tenantB`)),
  tenantC: dynamic(() => import(`../templates/tenantC`)),
};

const MultiTenantPage = ({ data }) => {
  // Provided template is present in the data
  // template: 'tenantA' || 'tenantB' || 'tenantC'
  const { template, ...rest } = data || {};

  // If the template doesn't exist, show a 404 Page instead
  const Component = templates[template] || (() => <Error statusCode="404" />);

  return <Component {...rest} />;
};

export default MultiTenantPage;
```

The multi-tenant page works well for us. We use a larger `revalidate` value because data isn't changing that often. Only caveat we had were a *little bit complex* test cases because of all the dynamic imports.

The above solution is very much similar to what you've considered for your use-case, albeit without an additional env variable (`IS_BUILD`)

Comment: That's such a nice answer, thanks! One question: I thought `getStaticPaths` does only work for dynamic pages (like `[someId].tsx`). How do you use it for non-dynamic ones (like `index.tsx`)? In my case, these sites can also show customer specific data.

Comment: You are correct. `getStaticPaths` only works for dynamic pages because it has to return a path. That's by design. (IMO feels more like a limitation). But there is a workaround, by using a dynamic page `[index].tsx`, returning `[]` in  `getStaticPaths`, add a check in `getStaticProps` to match the route `if (params.path !== '/customer')` and validate the path. You still get to keep a single path for your page, and return a 404 for path which does not match your if statement.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? How would one create the index page that way? Here's an example with two links, one to `/test` and one to `/test/1` - only the `/test/1` option works:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-pwjzop?file=pages%2Findex.js

Comment: Use the [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes). `[[...index]].js` and you can visit both `/test` and `/test/1` using a single file.

Comment: I think your proposal technically works, but I won't use it. It just feels way too hacky and probably does more harm than good. For example, when you initially want to visit such a static site, you're not redirected (click on one of the buttons): https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-yn8leh?file=pages%2Findex.js I think I will have to wait until Next.js decides to integrate such feature directly, I created a feature request: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/28959 Do you feel like I should accept your answer anyway?

Comment: I don't understand, "when you initially want to visit such a static site, you're not redirected". I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-optional-catch-all-sample-2f74v?file=/pages/test/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js) and it works as described. Is this not the expected behavior?